# Java: deepcopy list entry without instancing a new list

Tags: java, list, reference, copy, deep-copy

I've got a little problem while doing my programming task. I want to read some lines from a file (no problem so far) and tokenize it. Every line has about 4 tokens and each of them should find a place in a list. In the end, every line should be in a list too.

A little example to clarify this:

File Content:

> foo boo bar
> bii buu baa

output:

> [[foo, boo, bar], [bii, buu, baa]]

And heres the code I'm dealing with

```
String fileContent = fileloader(file.toString());
List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] lines = fileContent.split("\n"); 
for(String line:lines){
  String[] splittedLine = line.split("\t");
  for(String words:splittedLine){
    linesList.add(words);
  }
  lexiconContent.add(linesList); 
  linesList.removeAll(linesList);
}
```

I guess there's a problem with the references, because the first iteration works well! But in the second iteration, it copies the **actual** second content also to the first `(0)` list position and so on.

Finally I got something like `[[], [], [], []]`

Comment: `linesList.clear()` is probably faster/better to get a clean list for the next iteration.  Depending on what you're doing with lexiconContent, consider `lexiconContent.addAll(linesList)`.  It's adding each list element to lexiconContent, vs adding the list itself; but I think that's what you're asking for.

Comment: if you did want the list of lists, you're going to want to use a copy constructor, or `Collections.copy()` [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, you have created only one list, and adding a reference to that list to your outer list, by modifying it on each iteration. So, the final modification done to that list will be reflected for all the references.

You can solve this problem by creating a new `linesList` each time in the loop: -

```
List<String> linesList = null;  // Don't initialize here
String[] lines = fileContent.split("\n"); 

for(String line:lines){
    String[] splittedLine = line.split("\t");
    linesList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize a new list everytime.

    for(String words:splittedLine){
        linesList.add(words);
    }
    lexiconContent.add(linesList); 
}
```

And yes, you can also simplify your for loop to: -

```
for(String line:lines){
    String[] splittedLine = line.split("\t");
    lexiconContent.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splittedLine))); 
}
```

This way, you don't have to iterate over your array, and add individual elements to your List. In fact, you don't need an intermediate list at all.

Comment: I did! As you can see, I'm new here. Was always reading, never questioning before (:

Comment: @Daniello. You will gradually become familiar with the whole SO stuff. And of course reading answers on SO makes you feel good. Enjoy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code..Instead of creating new ArrayList for each iteration in loop: `for(String line:lines)` You are just adding the words (in nested loop) in the old object of `ArrayList` that you had used right from the first iteration of outer loop and storing that same reference value at all subsequent index of `lexiconContent` ArrayList.Also at the end of each iteration of outer loop you are clearing the `linesList` .So Finally you are remained with N number of entries in `lexiconContent`...Where the Element at each index of lexiconContent is nothing but the reference value of the single object of ArrayList(lineList) which is Empty!!!

```
You should use following code instead:
String fileContent = fileloader(file.toString());
List<String> linesList = null;
String[] lines = fileContent.split("\n"); 
for(String line:lines){
  List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<String>();
  String[] splittedLine = line.split("\t");
  for(String words:splittedLine){
    linesList.add(words);
  }
  lexiconContent.add(linesList); 
}
```